# Input text is empty using ng-model if value is provided

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I passed an array value in my view with `$userdata`.
In my view, there's a button there that will show a modal when triggered. This modal will show the user data using the `$userdata` variable.
Now, I used angular js for my form inputs.

For example:

```
div class="form-group">
    <label for="company_name" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Company Name</label>
    <div id="company_name" class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_name" value="{{$userData['company']['name']}}" ng-model="user.company_name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12">
       <span ng-show="userForm.company_name.$error.required && userForm.company_name.$touched"><br> <small><i>Name field is required</i></small></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is the input is not showing any value.
Why so? But when I removed the `ng-model` and just used a plain input field, the value will be shown.

Comment: you have to bind in ng-model not in value.

Comment: so it will not read the value from the userdata?

Comment: it will not display in your input box, use ng-model only and bind that value in that.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks @Dixit, I'll try that.

Comment: ohk, try and told me its working or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `value="..."` from input, `ng-model`  will control it. look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_model.asp) example.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_name"  ng-model="user.company_name" ng-required="true">
```